# AWS SAM CLI: sam deploy with python3.8 Image failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, aws-sam-cli

I'm trying to deploy the example app using `sam deploy -g` following [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started-hello-world.html).

Everything works as expected with `sam local invoke "HelloWorldFunction" -e events/event.json` and `sam local start-api`)

`sam deploy --guided` on the other hand is failing with:

> Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx; Proxy: null)

Following [this resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41389858), changing the get method to post didn't help either.
Below attached is a screenshot of the command output

Any help is greatly appreciated!

My local machine info:

```
OS: macOS BigSur version 11.1
Docker version 20.10.0, build 7287ab3
SAM CLI, version 1.15.0
aws-cli/2.1.15 Python/3.7.4 Darwin/20.2.0 exe/x86_64
```

[image: command output screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/) It is not available globally yet.

> You can use container images to deploy your Lambda functions today in US East (N. Virginia), US East (Ohio), US West (Oregon), Asia Pacific (Tokyo), Asia Pacific (Singapore), Europe (Ireland), Europe (Frankfurt), South America (São Paulo). We are working to add support in more Regions soon

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem but I think I have found where it comes from. It's a problem with the AWS region. My deployment doesn't work on the eu-west-3 (Paris) region but works on the eu-west-1 (Ireland) region. Hoping that AWS will fix the problem quickly, it's looking a bit amateurish to have a Getting Started that doesn't work :(